# Concatenar Matriz x Vetores

Tags: delphi

Tenho os seguintes valores em um StringList :

```
 1111,2222
 3333,4444
```

Tenho outro String list com os valores

```
 7777,8888
 9999,0000
```

Eu preciso adicionar os valores do segundo stringlist, concatenando na mesma posição em sequencia do primeiro 
Exemplo :

```
 1111,2222,7777,8888
 3333,4444,9999,0000
```

Como faço para acrescentar o conteúdo da segunda matriz de dados na primeira ?

Comment: Você deseja criar uma lista nova ou alterar a primeira? As duas listas sempre tem o mesmo número de linhas?

Answer (score 1):

Você tera que obter antes qual a Maior lista, digo, a que possui maior quantidade de dados, caso contrario vai ocorrer violação ou List of Bounds.

```
  for i := 0 to Pred(vLista1.Count) do
  begin
    vLista1.Strings[i] := vLista1.Strings[i] + ',' + vLista2.Strings[i];
  end;
```

Dessa forma estamos editando a Primeira Lista com os dados da Segunda exatamente na mesma ordem que estão os dados.

Answer (score 0):

Vê se te ajuda

```
var
 oSL1: TStringList;
 oSL2: TStringList;
 iCont1,iCont2: Integer;
 sValor: String;
begin
  oSL1 := TStringList.Create;
  oSL2 := TStringList.Create;
  try
    oSL1.Add('1111,2222');
    oSL1.Add('3333,4444');

    oSL2.Add('7777,8888');
    oSL2.Add('9999,0000');

    for iCont1 := 0 to oSL1.Count-1 do
    begin
      for iCont2 := 0 to oSL2.Count-1 do          
        sValor := oSL1.Strings[iCont1]+','+oSL2.Strings[iCont2];
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(oSL1);
    FreeAndNil(oSL2);
  end;
end;
```